# MediaSource never emit sourceopen event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-source

I'm trying to stream a video file using Javascript's MediaSource API in a React custom hook.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
const useMyHook = (videoRef: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLVideoElement | null>) => {
...
  useEffect(() => {
    const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    videoRef.current!.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
      // this never happens
    });
  }, []);
...
}
```

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null);
  const {} = useMyHook(videoRef);

  return (
    <>
      <video ref={videoRef} controls />;
    </>
  );
};
```

It looks like `mediaSource` never emit `'sourceopen'` event.

What more, when I'm trying to use this code in different project with simple html and javascript it works fine.

I was trying to use `document.getElementByTagName` instead of `useRef` or use this directly in my component, but with the same result.

Can somebody tell me what is the problem? Is there any problem with React or something?

Comment: In the current state your code in the `useEffect` hook should throw an error at the `videoRef.current!.src` line. Mind the `!`.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Does it even matter in my issue?

Comment: It would prevent the code from running and never reaching `mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen'...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate and maintain state of `MediaSource` throughout the scope of the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [mediaSource] = useState(new MediaSource())
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement | null>(null)

  // component init
  useEffect(() => {
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', ...)
  }, [])

  // videoRef changes
  useEffect(() => {
    videoRef?.current!.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)
  }, [videoRef])
};
```

Comment: Damn, it works!!! Thank you. I love you.